# Is there way to perform "if (condition) typedef ..."

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, typedef

I would like to perform a `typedef`, if and only if a compile-time condition is met. If the condition is not met, no `typedef` shall be performed at all.

Is that possible in C++11?

Example:

```
class A {
  std::conditional_typedef<true,int,myType1>; // Performs "typedef int myType1".
  std::conditional_typedef<false,int,myType2>; // Does nothing at all.
};
```

I am looking for this fictional `std::conditional_typedef`.

Comment: Could you provide some example code with that theoretical `if(...) typedef ...;` ? In particular, what should happen with code that uses the typedef if the typedef isn't "performed" ?

Comment: [std::enable_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if)

Comment: depending on condition specialization may be sufficient...

Comment: A simple almost-solution would be to conditionally typedef to the requested type, or to something that will be unusable in most cases, such as `void`. Would that fit your case ?

Comment: There is the venerable `#ifdef` ?

Comment: @JackAidley The preprocessor and the rest of the program C++ source code don't share a namespace so except in very certain circumstances the preprocessor isn't much use

Comment: @cat: All true, but beyond the desire for a compile-time switch the Asker hasn't told us what they want to do. The pre-processor may thus suffice.

Comment: Looks like you want something similar, but not identical, to [`std::conditional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Another way can be passing from the specialization of a base class

```
// foo is a light struct (only a typedef or not at all) that can be
// developed in two versions

template <bool>
struct foo;

template <>
struct foo<true>
 { typedef int myType1; }; // or using myType1 = int;

template <>
struct foo<false>
 { };

template <bool B>
struct bar : public foo<B> // B can be a type_traits value derived
                           // from template arguments for bar
 {
   // potential complex struct or class, developed only one time 
 };


int main()
 {
   bar<true>::myType1 mt1 { 1 };
   // bar<false>::myType1 mt2 { 1 }; error: ‘myType1’ is not a member of ‘bar<false>’
 }
```

Comment: Using inheritance appears to be a very natural way to solve the task.

Comment: Can't one do without the derived `bar` and directly use `foo<true>::myType1 mt1 {1}` ?

Comment: @chi - can be done; the advantage of using a base class (IMHO) is that you can develop two different specializations of a simple and light class with only (or without) a typedef; this permit to develop a single version of the derived class that can be complex.

Comment: @max66: Even though this technically use inheritance, I would be tempted to label this as mix-in instead. It's a very natural solution in templates.

Comment: @MatthieuM. - well... I'm not an expert and I'm bad in labelling but, yes, using templates I find it very natural.

Answer (score 16):

Unfortunately desired syntax can't be possible as names that are passed to the template instantiation have to be already defined. In your case `myType1` and `myType2` wouldn't name anything from compiler point of view. However if you're not insisting on the syntax you've mentioned you could try to use `std::enable_if` as follows:

```
#include <type_traits>

struct A {
    struct myType1: std::enable_if<true, int> { }; //std::conditional_typedef<true,int,myType1>; // Performs "typedef int myType1".
    struct myType2: std::enable_if<false, int> { }; //std::conditional_typedef<false,int,myType2>; // Does nothing at all.

};

int main() {
    A::myType1::type i;
    //A::myType2::type i2; // causes error: no type named 'type' in 'A::myType2'
    (void)i;
}
```

[[live demo]](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/7qk506rPt72kbeRb)

---

**Edit:**

Yet another way that came to my mind (utilizing using with default template parameter):

```
#include <type_traits>

struct A {
    template <class T = int>
    using myType1 = typename std::enable_if<true, T>::type;
    template <class T = int>
    using myType2 = typename std::enable_if<false, T>::type;
};

int main() {
    A::myType1<> i;
    //A::myType2<> j;
    (void)i;
}
```

[[live demo]](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/cZI6XlCiwIo7NSOd)

Answer (score 2):

Similar to std::enable_if, you could have your class descend from a template that does your typedef if you want to use your own names and not have to do A::mytype1::type. The downside is that you'd have to descend from multiple structs if you want to do this a lot.

```
namespace impl {
    template<bool, typename> struct A;
    template<typename T> struct A<true, T>{ typedef T mytype1; };
    template<typename T> struct A<false, T> {};
}

struct A : public impl::A<condition, int> {
    //If condition is met, then ::mytype1 will be defined as a typedef int
};

int main() {
    A::mytype1 i; //Will fail if condition wasn't met
}
```